# dots/ beads on a grid

Tags: combinatorics

I've got some difficulties with the following problem.

> We have an infinite grid. We put $4$ beads on the point $(0, 0)$. If we want to move a bead from $(x, y)$ we have to replace it with two other beads, one each on $(x+1, y)$ and $(x, y+1)$. Prove that after $n$ moves there is at least $1$ coordinate with two beads or more.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, this website is not for homework questions or for the regular Q&A pattern, but you have to mention what difficulties you faced, what is your level, the confusions you face. Use $\LaTeX$ for editing math.

Comment: What is *'at least 1  coordinate'* — a specific value of $x$ or $y$? Or rather a specific grid position $(x,y)$...?

Comment: Hi CiaPan,
"at least 1 coordinate" means "a specific grid position (x,y)". I've tried to prove it using induction on the number of moves (or the number of beads) but with no success. Pigeonhole principle also didn't help here...

Comment: Did you mean to write *re*move a bead? Else you would have to define in which way beads can be moved.

Comment: Hi dominik,
Given a bead on $(x,y)$, I can leave it in it's place or remove it from the grid and put two beads at $(x+1, y)$, and $(x, y+1)$

Answer (score 6):

As with many problems of this general sort, the trick is finding the right invariant.

Assign a weight of $2^{-n}$ to each bead sitting on a grid point that lies on the line $x+y=n$; the initial weight of the configuration is $4\cdot2^0=4$, and it’s easily checked that each move preserves the total weight.

After $n$ moves each bead lies on one of the lines $x+y=k$ with $k\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$. There are $k+1$ grid points on the line $x+y=k$, so if there is at most one bead on each grid point, the maximum possible weight is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k+1}{2^k}&<\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{k+1}{2^k}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{k}{2^k}+\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{2^k}\\
&=\frac{1/2}{(1-1/2)^2}+2\\
&=4\;.
\end{align*}$$

Since the actual total weight is $4$, there must be at least one grid point with at least two beads on it.